# Define background Image with UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, uiimageview

I'm using a header file to set the background for my application. I have something like:

```
#define backgroundImage [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpeg"]]
```

but I want use `UIImageView` instead of `UIColor`. I know I can do:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

but how do I use it with `#define`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#define is a preprocessor directive. What this is going to do is anywhere you use `backgroundImage` you will get `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpeg"]]`

The best way to handle this is use the #define to specify the image name:

```
#define kBackgroundImage @"background.png"
```

And then use that in your code:

```
// Use the table view bounds so the background view is the size of the table view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds;

[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kBackgroundImage]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

If you want to however, you can do:

```
#define kBackgroundImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]
```

And:

// Use the table view bounds so the background view is the size of the table view
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds;

```
[imageView setImage:kBackgroundImage];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

If you choose to make the whole code block a preprocessor define, you can use `\` to make new lines.

```
#define UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds; \
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kBackgroundImage]]; \
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same in swift?